# How do I show this :$\pi^n>n^{\pi} $ for $n\neq 3$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, pi

le $n$ be a positive integer such that $n\neq 3$ really i have tried to show this inequality  $\pi^n>n^{\pi} $ that is true for all positive integer n different from  $ n=3 $

Attempt: from the titled inequality for $n>3$ i have : $$n \log \pi >\pi \log n \tag {1}$$ .
from $(1)$  we have: $\displaystyle\frac{n}{\pi}> \displaystyle\frac{\log n}{\log \pi}\tag{2}$ , but the latter say nothing to us then my question is:

> > **Question**:How do I show this :$\pi^n>n^{\pi} $ for $n\neq 3$ if it is true  ?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zqk42rsq2n     $n = 3$ is the only integer where this is false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

Consider the function $f(x) = \pi\ln x - x \ln \pi$ for a fixed $n$ and find extrema using ordinary Calculus.

Comment: +1 Why not consider $f(x)=x\ln\pi-\pi\ln(x) ?$

Comment: @Isham could do it that way as well, your way is more direct, I agree -- changed it

Comment: Ok thanks was just curious...

Answer (score 4):

Your computations are fine. Another way of thinking about this is to see that the statement that you want to prove is equivalent to$$\frac n{\log n}>\frac\pi{\log\pi}.$$Now, consider the map $x\mapsto\dfrac x{\log x}$ and prove that it attains its minimal value when $x=e$ (which is smaller than $3$). Since $\frac4{\log4}\simeq2.89$ and $\frac\pi{\log\pi}\simeq2.74$, all you have to do is to check that the inequality holds when $n=1$ and when $n=2$.

Comment: There is a niggle here: the function is decreasing from $2$ to $e$ and then increasing from $e$ to $\pi$ and onwards... so the case $x=2$ needs to be solved directly... or by noticing that $\frac{2}{\log 2}=\frac{4}{\log 4}$... which follows from $2^4=4^2$.

Comment: @user8734617 I know. That's the reason for my final sentence.

Comment: Sure, but the final sentence could be interpreted as "take a calculator and check what's bigger", my point was - a calculator is not needed for that.

Comment: @user8734617 I missed the fact that that was you point.

Comment: It was, or at least it was meant to be... if I had not originally worded it so poorly; Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: your inequality its equivalent to this other $\frac{n}{\ln n}>\frac{\pi}{\ln \pi}$ for $n\neq 3$. Thus it is enough to study the function $f(x):=\frac{x}{\ln x}$.

> $f'(x)=0\iff \ln x=1$