# In which condition $a^b > b^a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I got stuck trying to find the relationship between $a$ and $b$ for $a^b > b^a$. Can anyone give some hints or tips?

Comment: Are $a,b$ positive real numbers or positive integers ? So or so, you can take the logarithm of the inequality and use the monotony of the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ to find the necessary conditions.

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586992/how-do-i-show-this-pinn-pi-for-n-neq-3)

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xdcvc7yod3

Answer (score 2):

We have $a^b>b^a$

Let's take the log of them to get $b\ln a>a\ln b\iff \frac a{\ln a}<\frac b{\ln b}$

---

Another approach is for fixed $a$ setting $f(x)=x\ln a-a\ln x$ and use calculus to find what we want. Well it is not the most simple way but if you know what the Lambert W function is you can find that the roots for this function are at $x=-\frac{aW\left(-\frac{\ln a}a\right)}{\ln a}$

Answer (score 1):

Taking the logarithm of both sides, we have $b\ln a>a\ln b$, meaning that $\frac{\ln b}b>\frac{\ln a}a$. Now, consider the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}x$. Taking the derivative, we get $f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$. This is positive when $x<e$. Therefore, $\frac{\ln b}b>\frac{\ln a}a$ if $a<b<e$. Similarly, $\frac{\ln b}b>\frac{\ln a}a$ if $e<b<a$. Therefore, $a^b>b^a$ if $a<b<e$ or $e<b<a$.

Comment: You meant ${lnb\over b} < {lna\over a}$ I guess.